# SQL quartiles transform

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, percentile

I have some data that I would like divided into quartiles based on row count. I've tried using ntile to do this but the part I'm having trouble with is transforing the data afterward. For example: the data may start out like this:

```
COLOR
red    
orange 
blue   
purple 
yellow 
black  
pink   
green
```

using ntile I get:

```
N | COLOR  
1 | yellow 
1 | red    
2 | purple 
2 | pink   
3 | orange 
3 | green  
4 | blue   
4 | black
```

desired output:

```
1      |2     |3      |4
yellow |purple|orange |blue
red    |pink  |green  |black
```

Thanks.

Comment: you've tagged the question with the answer: use a pivot query

Comment: `MAX(CASE WHEN color='yellow' THEN color END)as 1,` so on for each color..`GROUP BY`

Comment: How would I do that dynamically? This was just a simplified example; the real data may have 100+ values per quartile, so hard-coding isn't possible.

Comment: Specify your dbms first

Comment: @user3254331 do you always want the data presented in quarters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PIVOT to get the final result, but I would also suggest using a windowing function like `row_number()` to get it.   The windowing function will create a unique sequence for each `color` in your `ntile` value.

You should be able to use:

```
;with cte as
(
  select ntile(4) over(order by color desc) n, color 
  from yourtable
) 
select [1], [2], [3], [4]
from
(
  select n, color,
    row_number() over(partition by n order by n) seq
  from cte
) d
pivot
(
  max(color)
  for n in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfbd7/4)